# Alfresco Kikstart People selection

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti

I am new at Alfresco development.
I am using alfresco-enterprise-4.2.3.1 and using `Kikstart` to design a workflow. 
Workflow designed and installed successfully in `alfresco` and I can access that in `share`.

The issue is when I try to use a `People Selection` or `Group Selection` in the forms I get following error when I try to save/start workflow.

```
Failed to start workflow activiti$esclatedWF:1:1519
```

I have checked if I  remove these type of fields it works ok. Any help will appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There could be issue with alfresco share's configurations to read such "names "activiti$esclatedWF:1:1519"
Alfrsco is giving error because of those two : s in that name of workflow.
Could you check your logs and post the error from logs? If will give more idea.

Comment: @mitpatoliya my workflow name and id is `esclatedWF`. Those two `:` is just showing in error.
I am really new at alfresco.. Can you please give a tip where could I find the logs in alfresco ??? Thanks for reply

Comment: When I tried to start workflow from Alfresco explorer command `use definition activiti$esclatedWF:1:1519` it said


`definition: activiti$esclatedWF:1:1519 , name: esclatedWF , version: 1
workflow: None
path: None`